# Qt unit testing setup

Tags: unit-testing, qt

I've been using Qt for some time ... And I've decided to start using using unit test too (or at least try). But I don't know where to start ... I've read this:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qttest-index.html
and understand how to use QtTest class. But anything else I don't understand ... Should tests be in the same project as my actual project ? Or maybe in separate project ? Or maybe in many separated project ? If so, what's the criteria of separating them ?

And when I write some unit tests, how do I use them ? I mean, I will compile them, but then what ? I just ran executable file ? Do I need to compile my project separately or somehow include it in QtTest ? Can I automate the process, so all my unit test will be run automatically ?

Wow ... That's a lot of questions :) Can you give me link to some tutorial where these (I guess basic) things are covered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will be of some help:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qtestlib-tutorial.html

Comment: I've already read that ... But it doesn't give any information how to set up your project, or anything like that ... I guess it's more general unit-testing question ...